# Get Elapse time from Created and Modified Columns

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, calculated-column, date-time

I'd like to created a calculated column which subtracts the modified date/time from the creation date/time, is this possible?

EDIT: This worked for me - =TEXT(B2-A2,"h:mm:ss") replace the cell references with your actual columns.

Comment: Are you only interested in time difference. The above formula will not take days into account.

Comment: Yea I just realized that after midnight the time started over at 0. I'd like to get the total time, if it does into days i'd like to know that as well. Ex. 1 day 3 hours 45 minutes XX seconds

Answer (score 1):

```
=DATEDIF(Created,Modified,"d")&" days "&TEXT(Modified-Created,"hh:mm:ss")
```

This seems to be a slightly easier way to achieve it.  You could obviously tweak the second part to break out the hours, minutes and seconds if required.

The functions available in calculated columns are available here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862071%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Comment: The datedif doesn't give accurate results apparently, it doesn't consider time.

Comment: Yep - datediff will only give the difference in number of days - but the second part gives you the time component?

Comment: From what I understand it doesn't take into consideration time in calculating days.  So if I have day 18-15 it  will give me 3 days when the answer could actually be 2 days and 17 hours for example

Comment: Ah OK - so try passing in just the date element to the datediff?

Comment: This worked for me: =INT(Modified-Created)&" day(s) "&TEXT(Modified-Created,"h:mm:ss")

Comment: Excellent - glad you got it sorted :)

Answer (score 0):

One example over [here](http://kishansharepoint.blogspot.in/2012/05/common-datetime-formulas-for-sharepoint.html) shows Date Difference in days – Hours – Min format : e.g 4days 5hours 10min :

```
=YEAR(Today)-YEAR(Created)-IF(OR(MONTH(Today)<MONTH(Created),AND(MONTH(Today)=MONTH(Created),
DAY(Today)<DAY(Created))),1,0)&” years, “&MONTH(Today)-MONTH(Created)+IF(AND(MONTH(Today)
< =MONTH(Created),DAY(Today)<DAY(Created)),11,IF(AND(MONTH(Today)<MONTH(Created),DAY(Today)
> =DAY(Created)),12,IF(AND(MONTH(Today)>MONTH(Created),DAY(Today)<DAY(Created)),-1)))&” months,
“&Today-DATE(YEAR(Today),MONTH(Today)-IF(DAY(Today)<DAY(Created),1,0),DAY(Created))&” days”
```

This can help you accomplish your task.

Comment: I put this code as is and got a syntax error, am I suppose to change anything?

Comment: The Today function doesn't work in SP unfortunately

Comment: This was just an example to get you going.